# How do you convert Integer.MIN_VALUE to a positive long?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert this to a positive long but it is still printing as a negative. When I use other negative integers it works but not Integer.MIN_VALUE

```
 if(num == Integer.MIN_VALUE){
           long number = -num;
           System.out.println(number);
       }
```

Comment: You need to cast it to a long before you negate it.

Comment: That's because negative and positive are the same thing for `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `-2147483648`, but `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is only `2147483647`.  When you try to store an integer larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, it overflows into the next significant bit, which is the sign bit.  When you try to read the value, the runtime sees a negative number because the sign bit is set, so in this case it brings you right back to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  What you need to do is cast to a larger data type, so the next significant bit is no longer the sign bit.

Comment: Which positive long do you expect?

Comment: you could eventually use `Integer.toUnsignedLong()`, depending on use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`long num = -num;` is executed as:

1. take the int `num`, and negative it; it's still an `int`. In other words, it remains `Integer.MIN_VALUE` - because that's the one negative number amongst all 2^31 of em that doesn't have a positive equivalent, as `0` 'takes up space' on the positive side of things.
2. Then, take the number we now have (still `Integer.MIN_VAUE`, because `-Integer.MIN_VALUE` is still `Integer.MIN_VALUE`), and silently cast it to a `long`, because that's a widening (safe) conversion, so java will just inject the cast for you.

The fix is to first cast to a long and *then* negative it:

either:

```
long number = num;
number = -number;
```

or in one go:

```
long number = -((long) num);
```